# Symfony2, Forms - unset post values after form is valid

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to unset in Symfony2 values in form fields after validation is correct. I have something found on the net, like `$form->setName(null);` but I'm not sure, if this is the most effective way, also `unset($_POST);`.

Is there any way, how to unset posted values via form after `$form->isValid()` at once?

PS: I don't think that source codes are needed in this question.

**EDIT:**

If I try use `$form->setData(null)` in `isValid()` i'll get message of **You cannot change the data of a submitted form.**

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
unset($_POST[$form->getName()]);
```

Comment: Simply way is $form->setName(null); but I'm not sure, if it will work, if I am not using entity only constraints in form builder because it is just contact form. But i have 3 fields - name, email, content. I need to set all them to null after form is valid at once.

Comment: And your code is too incorrect, it will have form like this: unset($_POST['My name']) but it is a value not a key.